# ADVI Best Practices

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc, probabilistic-programming

I tried replicating the [stochastic vol example](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/getting_started.html#Case-study-1:-Stochastic-volatility) in the pymc3 documentation, but using a larger dataset.

NUTS was taking too long, so I tried ADVI.

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import pymc3 as pm
import pandas as pd

returns = data.get_data_yahoo('SPY', start='2008-5-1', end='2016-12-1')['Adj Close'].pct_change()

with pm.Model() as model:

    nu                 = pm.Exponential(name='nu', lam=1.0 / 10, testval=5.0)
    sigma              = pm.Exponential(name='sigma', lam=1.0 / .02, testval=0.1)
    s                  = pm.distributions.timeseries.GaussianRandomWalk(name='s', sd=sigma, shape=len(returns))
    volatility_process = pm.Deterministic(name='volatility_process', var=pm.math.exp(-2.0*s))
    r                  = pm.StudentT(name='r', nu=nu, mu=0.0, lam=1.0 / volatility_process, observed=returns)

    start   = pm.find_MAP()
    vparams = pm.variational.advi(start=start, n=5000)
    trace   = pm.variational.sample_vp(
        vparams = vparams,
        draws   = 10000
    )

fix, ax = sns.plt.subplots()
returns.plot(ax=ax)
ax.plot(returns.index, 1/np.exp(trace['s',::5].T), 'r', alpha=0.03)
```

Unfortunately, the results were not similar to what was in the documentation. It looked liked it was modeling a constant vol, rather than a stochastic vol which was what I was expecting.

Is this to be expected or did I do something wrong?
Is ADVI appropriate in this situation, and if not, why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to be cognizant of the assumptions underlying ADVI. At the core, it is a mean-field approximation (at least how it's implemented in PyMC3) which means that correlations in the posterior are ignored. This is fine for some models but the stochastic volatility model has a highly correlated posterior. The intuition is that s_t ~ N(s_{t-1}, sd^2) will be very correlated with s_{t-1}. Thus, the mean-field assumption is strongly violated here which leads to a bad approximation.

NUTS, on the other hand, is very good at exploring a very correlated, high-dimensional distribution, that's why this model is such a strong example for its power.